# WP7: Black screen when pressing back button when on browser

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

From my app MainPage I go to a website (alternatively: I go to task: send email). 
When pressing 'back button' black screen is returned, instead of MainPage. I have tried to find a solution, but have not found one yet. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you override the back button?

Comment: I have overridden it in the MainPage.xaml.cs to see that it ends the app when pressing back from there, but the blank screen appears when pressing back from the web site i went to. I do not think this override affect the problem?

Comment: Does it happen every time you go back? Or does it happen rarely? I have seen the same problem (sometimes empty page) happens very rarely..

Comment: Systematically all the time. The solution probably has something to do with things like 'Tombstoning' or/and 'changing code in App.xaml.cs.' to get the phone to remember from which page it came to internet from. I just do not know how to do this.

Comment: I.e. how can you put a reminder of from where you are leaving into App.xaml.cs under: Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
        { "here"  
        }

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve the problem (which I had but no one else, perhaps!). If you need to make an external link do not do it directly from your Main page. Instead create an intermediate page to go to, from where you link externally (to a website or the email application, for example). Then you come back to this page with the back arrow, and using a logical string, have been here ...have not been here, you can direct back to the main page. See below:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* instead of putting the code here, you go to another page
        EmailComposeTask emailcomposer = new EmailComposeTask();
        emailcomposer.To = "Ä;
        emailcomposer.Subject = "Customer request";
        emailcomposer.Body = "Text:";
        emailcomposer.Show();
        */

        var b = App.Current as App;
        b.Emailat = "email";

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

And on this other page:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var c = App.Current as App;
        string Howisit = c.Emailat;

        if (Howisit == "email")
        {
            EmailComposeTask emailcomposer = new EmailComposeTask();
            emailcomposer.To = "";
            emailcomposer.Subject = "Customer request";
            emailcomposer.Body = "Text:";
            emailcomposer.Show();

            var b = App.Current as App;
            b.Emailat = "stop";
        }

        if (Howisit == "stop")
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }


    }
```

That's it!